# Note Taking App using local storage

Tags: javascript, html, web

Trying to create a note taking app for school but I'm confused on some things. How do I make it so that when I type into a form block, it will save whatever I put inside of the text block even after you refresh the page.

I am a little confused on how local storage works. A simple answer with a block of code of the javascript would be nice. df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The localStorage API is very simple and easy to use, you can find the APIs basic usage information on its MDN page: [localStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and the page for web storage: [Web Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

I've also provided a JSFiddle example, for how an application similar to yours would function using the API, which can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fzd29evu/).

There are multiple ways to set and get values using the API
Example:

```
// Using the getItem & setItem funcitons
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value'); // sets 'key' to 'value'
localStorage.getItem('key'); // returns: 'value'

// Simple member assignment
localStorage.note = 'value'; // 'note' => 'value'
localStorage.note; // 'value'
localStorage['note2'] = 'some other value';  // 'note2' => 'some other value'
localStorage['note2']; // 'some other value'
```